# Filtering command output and print to file?

Tags: bash, process, grep, output, filtering

I am currently launching this bash line `command -option | grep -A 1 --color 'string1\|string2'` to filter the output of a process. Instead of printing the filtered output on console, how can I print the output on file?

I tried: `command -option | grep -A 1 'string1\|string2' >> test.txt` but it didn't print anything on file.

I also tried by adding the regular expression option: `command -option | grep -E -A 1 'string1|string2' >> test.txt` but I still got an empty file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the issue was with buffering. By buffering line by line the problem is solved.

```
 command -option | grep --line-buffered -A 1 'string1\|string2' >> test.txt
```